# numpy interpolation with period

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain to me the code that is in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) specifically this:

> Interpolation with periodic x-coordinates:
>
> x = [-180, -170, -185, 185, -10, -5, 0, 365]
>
> xp = [190, -190, 350, -350]
>
> fp = [5, 10, 3, 4]
>
> np.interp(x, xp, fp, period=360)
>
> array([7.5 , 5.  , 8.75, 6.25, 3.  ,
> 3.25, 3.5 , 3.75])

I did a trial like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [-180, -170, -185, 185, -10, -5, 0, 365]
xp = [190, -190, 350, -350]
fp = [5, 10, 3, 4]

y=np.interp(x, xp, fp, period=360)
print(x)
print(y)


plt.grid()
plt.plot(xp, fp)
#plt.scatter(x,y,marker="o",color="green")
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.show()
```

and it shows like this

[image: interpolation]

How the orange points can be considered "interpolations" is beyond me. They are not even in the curve

EDIT: Thanks to Warren Weckesser for the detailed explanation!
A plot to see it better

[image]

Comment: The values in `x` are not sorted.  `matplotlib`'s `plot` function plots the curve in the order given; it does not sort the values for you.  If the `x` values jump back and forth, then the "curve" (i.e. the line segments that connect the given points) will also jump back and forth.

Comment: My previous comment also applies to your plot of `(xp, fp)`, because the values in `xp` are not sorted.  Maybe change the plot of these points to a scatter plot, e.g. `plt.plot(xp, fp, 'o')`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, thanks. I understood that too. I just left it like that to see the contrast between my original wrong plot and the new one with your correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers used in the example that demonstrates the use of `period` in the `interp` docstring can be a bit difficult to interpret in a plot.  Here's what is happening...

The period is 360, and the given "known" points are

```
xp = [190, -190, 350, -350]
fp = [  5,   10,   3,    4]
```

Note that the values in `xp` span an interval longer than 360.  Let's consider the interval [0, 360) to be the fundamental domain of the interpolator.  If we map the given points to the fundamental domain, they are:

```
xp1 = [190, 170, 350, 10]
fp1 = [  5,  10,   3,  4]
```

Now for a periodic interpolator, we can imagine this data being extended periodically in the positive and negative directions, e.g.

```
xp_ext = [..., 190-360, 170-360, 350-360, 10-360, 190, 170, 350, 10, 190+360, 170+360, 350+360, 10+360, ...]
fp_ext = [...,       5,      10,       3,      4,   5,  10,   3,  4,       5,      10,       3,      4, ...]
```

It is this extended data that `interp` is interpolating.

Here's a script that replaces the array `x` from the example with a dense set of points.  With this dense set, the plot of `y = np.interp(x, xp, fp, period=360)` should make clearer what is going on:

```
xp = [190, -190, 350, -350]
fp = [5, 10, 3, 4]
x = np.linspace(-360, 720, 1200)
y = np.interp(x, xp, fp, period=360)
plt.plot(x, y, '--')
plt.plot(xp, fp, 'ko')
plt.grid(True)
```

[image: plot]

Each "corner" in the plot is at a point in the periodically extended version of `(xp, fp)`.

Comment: Wow, that was really complicated, but I understood it. The docs really need this explanation!  I added a plot to see the relationship